# How to apply the utility Packages for Numerical Differential Equation Solving

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, interpolation, packages

I have solved two coupled equations with `{Solf, Solg} = NDSolveValue[eqns, {f, g}, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}]` and want to extract the computational grid `{x,t}` with `InterpolatingFunctionDomain` and `InterpolatingFunctionGrid` to observe the spatial mesh and to plot the time steps. In addition, sometimes it cannot compute a solution over the full time-interval that I specified, so I want to plot the solution that was computed in order to understand what might have gone wrong.

By reading the [document](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html), I know how to do this when using `NDSolve` to solve a single equation for `h[x,t]`. For example,

```
hSol = First[h/.NDSolve[eqn, f, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}]]

hGrid = InterpolatingFunctionGrid[hSol]

Dimensions[hGrid] (*determine mesh points in each dimension*)

{Tini, Tfinal} = InterpolatingFunctionDomain[hSol][[2]] (*extract the time interval*)

tList = hGrid[[mesh-position, All, 2]]; (*here the 'mesh-position' can be chosen according to the output of Dimensions[hGrid]*)
```

Then we can plot the time steps at the mesh-position using

```
ListLogPlot[tList, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"step", "t"}]
```

**But I cannot extend these to the case in which I used `NDSolveValue` to solve two coupled equations for `f[x,t]` and `g[x,t]`, as mentioned above.** For example, using `hGrid = InterpolatingFunctionGrid[Solf]` and `Dimensions[hGrid]` I obtained `{1}`, which was clearly wrong and should be in the form of `{number-of-space-mesh, number-of-time-step, 2}`.

I think the problem results form the structure of the output of `{Solf, Solg} = NDSolveValue[...]`. In this case the output is in this form: `{InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,L},{0.,tmax}},<>],InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,L},{0.,tmax}},<>]}`. Please help.

Here is an example from the document of `NDSolveValue`:

```
pde={\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[t, x]\)\)==\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\((\((v[t, x] - 1)\)\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]u[t, x])\)\)+(16 x t-2 t-16 (v[t,x]-1)) (u[t,x]-1)+10 x E^(-4 x),\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(v[t, x]\)\)==\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({x, 2}\)]\(v[t, x]\)\)+\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(u[t, x]\)\)+4 u[t,x]-4+x^2-2 t-10 t E^(-4 x)};

bc={u[0,x]==1,v[0,x]==1,u[t,0]==1,v[t,0]==1,3 u[t,1]+(u^(0,1))[t,1]==3,5 (v^(0,1))[t,1]==E^4 (u[t,1]-1)};

{usol, vsol} = NDSolveValue[{pde, bc}, {u, v}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: There should be no difference. Please show us a specific example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @xzczd please see the update.

Comment: You haven't pasted the example correctly. After correcting the mistake, the output of `InterpolatingFunctionGrid@usol // Dimensions` is `{38,25,2}`.

Comment: Thank you @xzczd, but how to plot the time step in the middle of space (i.e. position `19`) with `ListLogPlot[tList, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"step", "t"}]`?

Comment: In this case `NDSolve` is using a uniform grid i.e. just choose any member of 2nd dimension: e.g. `usol["Grid"][[All, 1, 1]] // ListPlot`, or even simpler: `usol["Coordinates"][[1]] // ListPlot`